# MDI Child form painting issue

Tags: c#, forms, paint

```
  Do anyone have any comments about this issue.
```

[image]

This is a MDI Child form displayed inside a MDI Client.And when i overlaps the forms partially on to another form then its no fully repainted. Is this a painting issue.Do anyone have any idea.

Thanks in advance
Sunil

Comment: What is the code you use for showing this MDI form?

Comment: I have a panel inside which i have added a MDI Client             private Form mdiForm;
        private MdiClient ctlClient = new MdiClient();
        public MDIFormPanel()
        {
            base.Controls.Add(this.ctlClient);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 Form2 f2;    

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (f2 == null) {
       f2 = new Form2();
       f2.MdiParent = this;
       f2.FormClosed += delegate { f2 = null; };
       f2.Show();
    }
    else {
       f2.Activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the hint from your answer. I Invalidated my child forms on its activate event. Any way thanks for your help.